# Upgrading from gridgain to Apache Ignite

Tags: gridgain, ignite

We're currently running gridgain 6.2.1. Is there an existing upgrade guide  in order to transition to apache ignite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such guide and it highly depends on what parts of GridGain you're using. All functionality that existed in 6.x was migrated to Ignite with a bit different API. So I suggest to update the version and start fixing compilation step by step.